# Laravel: Session message exist while click on browser back button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, laravel-5.5

In `Laravel 5.5`, I am having `crud` operation for slider, the store method is as follows

```
public function store(StoreSlider $request)
{  
    $image = $request->image;
    $name = $request->name;
    $status = $request->status;

    $path = Storage::putFile('slider', $image);
    Slider::create([ 'name' => $name, 'image' => $path, 'status' => $status ]);
    Session::flash('message', 'Slider added successfullly'); 
    return redirect()->route('slider.index');
}
```

It redirects to `index` page, and shows the message *Slider added successfullly* and i am using the below code to display the session:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <p class="alert_msg"><i class="icon-correct-signal"></i> {{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

and i am hiding the above message with the following code,

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert_msg').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);
```

All the above are working fine.

In `index` page the message once shows and hides.

In `index` page having `view option`, that show the added slider, if i come back by click any `URL`, the session message not showing. Perfect

*The problem is while in `view` page i come back by click on browser back button the session message shows again*

Can't able to find whats the issue.

Comment: telling your browser to go back doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @lagbox if i refresh the session message gone, fine. But if i click on view uri and comeback by click on browser back the session message still exist. thats weired right?

Comment: no ... its going back in history to what was the previous loaded page's content

Comment: yes, right... how can i sort this out?

Answer (score 3):

use the following headers

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: this will remove all cache storage